# ElasticSearch C# client (NEST): Filtering results with ES 5.5.0

Tags: elasticsearch, filtering, nest

This was my code in the earlier version of ES it used to work. After moving to ES 5.5. It has stopped working and it gives a compiler error.

Error: 'QueryStringQueryDescriptor' does not contain a definition for 'OnFields' and no extension method 'OnFields' accepting a first argument of type 'QueryStringQueryDescriptor'

Below is my code snippet...

```
    public List<EmployeeInfo> SearchText2(string query, List<string> sendersList, int page = 0, int pageSize = 50)
    {
        try
        {

            var result = this.client.Search<EmployeeInfo>(s => s
                 .From(page * pageSize)
                 .Size(int.MaxValue)
                 .Query(q => q
                            .QueryString(qs => qs.Query(query).UseDisMax()
                            .OnFields(b => b.Subject)
                            .OnFields(b => b.Body)
                            ))
                .SortDescending(f => f.ReceivedTime)
                 .Filter(f => f.Terms(ak => ak.SenderName, sendersList))

                            );

                   ...
                   // Some code here

        }
```

Any tips on how to make this work will be great.

Answer (score 2):

In latest version of `Nest` library there are some API changes

1. Instead of `OnFields` in `QueryString` you should use `Fields`

   ```
   QueryString(qs => qs.Query(string.Empty).UseDisMax()
       .Fields(descriptor => descriptor.Fields(b => b.Subject, b => b.Body))
   ))
   ```
2. Instead of `SortDescending` you should use `Sort`

   ```
   .Sort(descriptor => descriptor.Field(f => f.ReceivedTime, SortOrder.Descending))
   ```
3. Also the filters are not available in elasticsearch starting from version 5 and you should use bool query with filter

   ```
   Query(descriptor => 
       descriptor.Bool(boolQuery => 
           boolQuery
               .Must(query => query.MatchAll())
               .Filter(f => f.Terms(ak => ak.SenderName, sendersList)
           )
       )
   )
   ```

Comment: var result = this.client.Search<EmployeeInfo>(a => a
.Type(IndexName)
.Size(int.MaxValue)
.Query(q => q
.QueryString(qs => qs.Query(string.Empty).UseDisMax()
.Fields(ft => ft.Fields(b => b.City, b => b.State, b => b.Zip))))
.Bool(blQuery => blQuery
.Must(query1 => query1.MatchAll())
.Filter(f => f.Term(ak => ak.Field(b => b.City).Value(sendersList))))));
error CS1061: 'SearchDescriptor<EmployeeInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'Bool' and no extension method 'Bool' accepting a first argument of type 'SearchDescriptor<EmployeeInfo>' could be found

Comment: Still get an error. Need help please. error CS1061: 'SearchDescriptor<EmployeeInfo>' does not contain a definition for 'Bool' and no extension method 'Bool' accepting a first argument of type 'SearchDescriptor<EmployeeInfo>' could be found

Comment: what version of nest client are you using?

Comment: ES is 5.5.0 and Nest is 5.3.1